# Прямой доступ к оборудованию под Linux

Tags: железо, c, c++, linux

Имеется рабочая машинка с ОС Linux. Требуется получить из консольного пользовательского приложения (ring3) доступ к портам ввода-вывода.

Под ОС Windows эта проблема решается следующими способами:

1. драйвер типа userport или giveio -> прямо в программе делаем ввод-вывод через команды asm'а in/out
2. собственный драйвер "виртуального у-ва", который в ring0 делает всю черновую работу и      предоставляет некий интерфейс с помощью IOCTL прикладным программам. Пользовательское приложение вызывает соответствующие IOCTL'ы.

Какие варианты есть под Linux? Прошу снадбить короткими примерами кода.

PS: ес-но root'овые привилегии имеют место быть.

Comment: Плюс: мне тоже это интересно, хоть я с линуксом практически и не занимался.

Comment: Простите, Вы не могли бы написать по поводу IoCtrl'ов в вопрос <a href=http://hashcode.ru/questions/17707/%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80-%D0%B2-win32>акселерометр-в-win32</a> , а то у меня как раз с Windows'ким  драйвером нужно разбираться? =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, основной способ в Linux следовать тем же путём: делаете модуль ядра, который работает с портами ввода-вывода и предоставляет какой-то интерфейс для приложений, например, создаёт tty или какой-то другой файл-устройство и, возможно, предоставляет IOCTL; а из приложения обращаетесь к этому файлу-устройству и работаете с драйвером через него. Пример приведу позже, если другие не приведут. Однако, кое какие примеры можно легко найти в интернете. Например: [Character Device Drivers](http://www.faqs.org/docs/kernel/x571.html). И вообще, если вы планируете идти по первому пути, то не мешает пролистать этот [The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/index.html), который является классикой жанра из категории MUST READ. Вот ещё то же (или почти то же), на русском: [The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide (RU)](http://www.linuxcenter.ru/lib/books/lkmpg.phtml). Или вот ещё пример: [Implementing a Simple Char Device in Linux](http://linuxgazette.net/125/mishra.html)

Ну и конечно многие устройства при подключении определяются как serial port или что-то подобное и тогда соответствующий модуль ядра создаёт этот самый файл-устройство и тогда вам надо просто понять, что с этим файлом-устройством делать.

Второй путь - это использовать user space device driver API. Почитайте, например тут: [User-space device drivers](http://tldp.org/LDP/khg/HyperNews/get/devices/fake.html)

Comment: Ну, что ж, ждем-с пока товарищи активизируются...

Comment: Сорри, нет сейчас времени пример писать :) Всё пробегом тут отвечаю. Второй путь вообще набирает популярность, так что не мешает и попробовать его. Добавил пару ссылок на простые примеры по первой части