# Написание драйвера Linux с работой с прикладным ПО

Tags: linux, драйвер

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите статьи/книги/треды форумов на тему написания драйверов сетевых устройств под Linux. Интересно написать драйвер, который будет взаимодействовать с обычным пользовательским приложением (наподобии FUSE, только сеть).

Спасибо.

Comment: желающим помочь с подобными вопросами: просьба дополнить [описание метки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/linux/info) (а лучше — [этой](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/kernel/info)) ссылками из ответов на эти вопросы: [1](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/371064/178576), [2](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/8509/178576) и [3](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/444474/178576). а данный вопрос, конечно, следует закрыть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Основная книжка по драйверам Linux: "Драйверы Устройств Linux, Третья Редакция". Это перевод книги "Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition"
   by Jonathan Corbet, Alessandro Rubini, and Greg Kroah-Hartman
2. "Программирование модулей ядра Linux" Олег Цилюрик.
3. "Linux PCI drivers" Michael Opdenacker Free Electrons. Поскольку практически все сетевые карточки - PCI-ные.

Конкретно по сетевым драйверам:
http://rus-linux.net/lib.php?name=/MyLDP/algol/realtekdriver.html

Конкретно по FUSE:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-fuse/